# how to sort material ui datagrid table without affecting total sum rows inside a datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

This is my codeSandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/making-sum-of-column-in-datagrid-mui-zjzfq6?file=/demo.js

So,when I sort by ascending then subtotal,total and tax rows come up but when sort by descending they comes down .How can I sort by ascending without affecting subtotal, tax and total rows.so that they remain at bottom when someone sort.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the solution to it.

If you check out the MUI docs on column spanning:
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-spanning/

They've mentioned that you should disable sort for the columns affected by colSpan. You should be able to modify the following from the doc to suit your code requirements:

> {
> field: 'organization',
> sortable: false,
> filterable: false,
> hideable: false,
> },

Comment: but if I want sorting for colspan column then how to resolve this?